# Showing data related to a logged in user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am building this simple system for a school, where students can log in to see their results at the end of every semester. I designed a model for exams with a manytomany relationship to a user. My problems is in my template am finding it hard to show a exams results related to a logged in user.

`models.py`

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    other_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    birth_of_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    birth_Of_admission = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True, )
    passport_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='passport_picture', null=True, blank=True,
                                         help_text='Upload the passport picture here')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            StudentProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.studentprofile.save()


    class Subject(models.Model):
        subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name


    class Year(models.Model):
        year = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year


    class Exam(models.Model):
        TERM_CHOICES = (
            ('First Term', 'First Term'),
            ('Second Term', 'Second Term'),
            ('Third Term', 'Third Term')
        )
        level = models.ForeignKey('Level', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        student = models.ForeignKey(Year, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        year = models.ForeignKey(Year, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        term = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="", choices=TERM_CHOICES)
        mid_term_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='the marks scored for mid term exams')
        End_of_term_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='the marks scored for end of  term exams')
        class_work_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='the marks scored for class work')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.subject + "-" + self.term
```

`views.py`

```
class StudentView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Exam
    template_name = 'student.html'
    context_object_name = 'student'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.exam
```

What I am trying to do is to show logged in student only his results based on the exams he has taken and but is rather showing me all. Even those he has not taken.

Answer (score 0):

you can `retrive` those exams by `set_all` look_up_relationship or manually can query on Exam model.

possible way can be like this

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user.exam_set.all()
```

Also you can try this

```
def get_object(self):
    return Exam.objects.filter(student_id=self.request.user.id)
```

## Edit

If i understand you properly now, then student's current level is an important factor of this `Exam` filtering. We should add that too than, otherwise all exam will appear. But from your `Exam` model structure, i haven't see any `level` entity associated with User model present. I am assuming term and level actually same thing ( most likely which are not )

```
def get_object(self):
        return Exam.objects.filter(student_id=self.request.user.id, term = self.request.user.level )
```

Comment: Both suggested solutions are not working.All the exams that the logged in user did not take keeps showing in the template.But i what to show only the ones he took. Is here anything wrong with my model relationships

Comment: Then you need to passed that particular `exam_id` from your template. Can you please elaborate your requirements in details, what you actually want to do.

Comment: What am trying to do is, students have the ability to take a couple of exams based on their level.I want them to see their results for he exams they have taken when they login into their account

Comment: @RobertNgnantibeYenji i think there is a relation between student's model `level` entity to `Exam` model's term or any other field. You need to add those in your filtering. I have edited my answer. please check that and give me your feedback.

Comment: i have added the the level to the model but still its not working. Take a look at my template code and see if am doing things right at the template level {% for exam in student %} {{ exam.subject }} {{ exam.class_work_score }} {{ exam.mid_term_score }} {{ exam.End_of_term_score }} {% endfor %}

Comment: @RobertNgnantibeYenji can you please edit your question with your changed model, view  , and template.